# Add search suggestion in both API and site on broadleaf community edition

Tags: broadleaf-commerce

How to add search suggestion in site and API similar to broadleaf demo site?

I can't find search suggestion in my broadleaf spring-boot community edition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by adding list of keywords for every product.

In schema.xml
1. Add a new field keyword for storing keywords from db
2. Add copyfield suggest_phrase for suggestion
3. copy keyword, manufacture field in suggest_phrase.

In solrconfig.xml,
1. Create searchcomponent in the name of "suggest"
2. Create request handler "/suggest" for that component which should have field as suggest_phrase.

Extend SolrSearchIndexImpl.java to add keywords in solr while reindexing.
You will get keywords as suggestion.